# Spring Boot - Resolve placeholders in the main app when testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, property-placeholder

I've had a hard time launching Spring tests - placeholders don't seem to be resolved in the main program while testing.
For instance, there is a RESTController method:

```
@RequestMapping("${hello_path}")
private String helloWorld() {
    return env.getProperty("hello_content");
}
```

as you see there's a placeholder in `@RequestMapping` annotation.

It works when I test it manually (i.e., the endpoint is created and accessible), but programmatical tests fall through:

```
@Test
public void searchReqController_saysHello() throws Exception {
    //given
    final String helloPath = env.getProperty("hello_path");
    final String helloContent = env.getProperty("hello_content");

    //when-then
    this.mockSearchReqController.perform(get(helloPath)).andExpect
                (status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string(helloContent));
}
```

results in

```
Invalid mapping on handler class [ebi.ensembl.ftpsearchapi.SearchRequestController]: private java.lang.String ebi.ensembl.ftpsearchapi.SearchRequestController.helloWorld()
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mapping on handler class [ebi.ensembl.ftpsearchapi.SearchRequestController]: private java.lang.String ebi.ensembl.ftpsearchapi.SearchRequestController.helloWorld()
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.inspect(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector$1.doWith(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticRequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:490)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.registerMvcSingletons(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:356)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.initWebAppContext(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:341)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.AbstractMockMvcBuilder.build(AbstractMockMvcBuilder.java:139)
    at ebi.ensembl.ftpsearchapi.FtpSearchApiApplicationTests.setup(FtpSearchApiApplicationTests.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:114)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'hello_path' in value "${hello_path}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.StandaloneMockMvcBuilder$StaticStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(StandaloneMockMvcBuilder.java:517)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.resolveEmbeddedValuesInPatterns(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.inspect(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:235)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @EnableWebMvc for @RestController to work. Also Try adding $.hello_path while calling the controller in test class